# Custom message box in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, messagebox, dotnetnuke-5

I am trying to bring in a Custom message box functionality for an application developed using the DotnetNuke CMS.When i googled i came across this link [source code in Java for message box display](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/javatip48/MessageBox.java)

I have no idea on Java.Now i would like to know:

1. If this source code for a stand alone application developed in Java.Will this be possible to use for the Server-Client web applications?
2. Is there any way i can directly use this function in my DotnetNuke/Asp.net applications considering the possibilities of Java applets?.This question stands only if for the 1st question it is Yes.

Out of curiosity: Is it possible for the Java application be used along with the Asp.net application(Will the frame work be able to handle it).I assume it wouldn't be.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is Java AWT code and can't be used in your HTML. It is meant to be used in desktop applications and not in webpages.

I am not sure about DotNetNuke but in ASP.NET you can create a custom message box two ways:

1. Create a new ASPX page and then call it using JavaScript's window.open() function specifying the width, height and position.
2. Use a JavaScript framework like jQuery (or plain old JavaScript) and you can display a div tag's content as a modal or non-modal message box. Here is an example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated